# Reducing NbClust memory usage

Tags: r, memory, cluster-analysis, matrix-multiplication

I need some help with massive usage of memory by the NbClust function.
On my data, memory balloons to 56GB at which point R crashes with a fatal error. Using `debug()`, I was able to trace the error to these lines:

```
            if (any(indice == 23) || (indice == 32)) {
                res[nc - min_nc + 1, 23] <- Index.sPlussMoins(cl1 = cl1, 
                    md = md)$gamma
```

Debugging of Index.sPlussMoins revealed that the crash happens during a for loop. The iteration that it crashes at varies, and during the loop memory usage varies between 41 and 57Gb (I have 64 total):

```
    for (k in 1:nwithin1) {
      s.plus <- s.plus + (colSums(outer(between.dist1, 
                                        within.dist1[k], ">")))
      s.moins <- s.moins + (colSums(outer(between.dist1, 
                                          within.dist1[k], "<")))
      print(s.moins)
    }
```

I'm guessing that the memory usage comes from the `outer()` function.
Can I modify NbClust to be more memory efficient (perhaps using the bigmemory package)? 
At very least, it would be nice to get R to exit the function with an "cannot allocate vector of size..." instead of crashing. That way I would have an idea of just how much more memory I need to handle the matrix causing the crash.

Edit: I created a minimal example with a matrix the approximate size of the one I am using, although now it crashes at a different point, when the hclust function is called:

```
set.seed(123)

cluster_means = sample(1:25, 10)
mlist = list()
for(cm in cluster_means){
  name = as.character(cm)
  m = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(60000*60,mean=cm,sd=runif(1, 0.5, 3.5)), 60000, 60))
  mlist[[name]] = m
}

test_data = do.call(cbind, cbind(mlist))

library(NbClust)
debug(fun = "NbClust")
nbc = NbClust(data = test_data, diss = NULL, distance = "euclidean", min.nc = 2, max.nc = 30, 
              method = "ward.D2", index = "alllong", alphaBeale = 0.1)
```

```
debug: hc <- hclust(md, method = "ward.D2")
```

It seems to crash before using up available memory (according to my system monitor, 34Gb is being used when it crashes out of 64 total.

So is there any way I can  do this without sub-sampling manageable sized matrices? And if I did, how do I know how much memory I will need for a matrix of a given size? I would have thought my 64Gb would be enough.

Edit:
I tried altering NbClust to use fastcluster instead of the stats version. It didn't crash, but did exit with a memory error:

```
Browse[2]> 
exiting from: fastcluster::hclust(md, method = "ward.D2")
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 9.3 Gb
```

Comment: Great question! However, we need a reproducible example to see how exactly the memory explodes. Can you please post the whole script? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: OK, I'm making a minimal example using dummy data. I'm not sure about posting the entire NbClust script, it is thousands of lines long and can be read on GitHub. https://github.com/cran/NbClust/blob/master/R/NbClust.R

Answer (score 1):

If you check the source code of Nbclust, you'll see that is all but optimized for speed or memory efficiency.

The crash you're reporting is not even during clustering - it's in the evaluation afterwards, specifically in the "Gamma, Gplus and Tau" index code. *Disable* these indexes and you may get further, but most likely you'll just have the same problem again in another index. Maybe you can pick only a few indices to run, specifically such indices that so *not* need a lot of memory?

Comment: Commenting out those lines lines did allow the current dataset to run to completion. I think I might have screwed up the structure of output though. It's a pretty complicated function, so mucking about with it like this bothers me.

Comment: But you are correct, with a larger matrix it crashed at a different point.

Comment: You don't need to comment the lines and guess. Study the evaluation methods, and set the parameter to only include those that are O(n) not O(n²).

Comment: Sorry if this is an overly basic question, but how do I know? Can you point me to a relevant explanation of O-notation in the context of optimizing R functions?

Comment: You'll need to check the relevant literature. I don't know which of these indices is based on pairwise distances. But it should be easy to see both in code and mathematical definition. If in doubt, don't use it - use only those that seem to be okay.

Comment: You also cannot use the initialization with hierarchical clustering (`hclust` is O(n²) memory and O(n³) time!), as this is both too slow and needs to much memory. There are alternatives - IIRC, the ELKI version of EM should run in O(nk), hence be more scalable.

Answer (score 0):

I forked NbClust and made some changes that seem to have made it go for longer without crashing with bigger matrices. I changed some of the functions to use `Rfast`, `propagate` and `fastcluster`. However there are still problems.

I haven't run all my data yet and only run a few tests on dummy data with `gap`, so there is still time for it to fail. But any suggestions/criticisms would be welcome.
My (in progress) fork of NbCluster:
https://github.com/jbhanks/NbClust